Missing libraries - FreeCAD AppImage
Ubuntu 24.04, in fairly "clean" state, all updates, installed in a VM, VMWare 17.5.2.
Attempting to run a freshly downloaded FreeCAD AppImage
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hannu hannu 848377024  2024-06-27_13.19.56  FreeCAD-0.21.2-Linux-x86_64.AppImage*

The environment appears to require a couple extra libs (not present in the AppImage). Providing them from
$ apt-file find zink_
libgl1-mesa-dri: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/zink_dri.so
$ apt-file find swrast_
libgl1-mesa-dri: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
libgl1-mesa-dri: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
$ 

... does not solve the problem, due to "missing symbols", library versions not the expected ones, I presume.
Any ideas further from here?

$ ./FreeCAD-0.21.2-Linux-x86_64.AppImage 
FreeCAD 0.21.2, Libs: 0.21.2R33771 (Git)
© Juergen Riegel, Werner Mayer, Yorik van Havre and others 2001-2023
FreeCAD is free and open-source software licensed under the terms of LGPL2+ license.
FreeCAD wouldn't be possible without FreeCAD community.
  #####                 ####  ###   ####  
  #                    #      # #   #   # 
  #     ##  #### ####  #     #   #  #   # 
  ####  # # #  # #  #  #     #####  #   # 
  #     #   #### ####  #    #     # #   # 
  #     #   #    #     #    #     # #   #  ##  ##  ##
  #     #   #### ####   ### #     # ####   ##  ##  ##

MESA-LOADER: failed to open zink: /usr/lib/dri/zink_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_va_get_start_addr (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_va_get_start_addr (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
WebEngineContext used before QtWebEngine::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed.
QGLXContext: Failed to create dummy context
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DefaultSwapBehavior, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile) 
/tmp/.mount_FreeCAao58pf/AppRun: line 43:  3730 Aborted                 (core dumped) ${MAIN} "$@"
$

Doing it "manually" allows to add files...
t="$(mktemp -d -p .)" 
cd "$t"
../FreeCAD-0.21.2-Linux-x86_64.AppImage --appimage-extract   
cd squashfs-root/
#
# replace / provide libraries... manually
#
./AppRun
cd ../..
rm -rf "$t" 

